# Lazy Load batch dataset Keras

Tags: dataset, keras

I'm beginner in the Keras, I need to load lazyed batches of the dataset because my dataset has more of 15k images.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ImageDataGenerator` in keras

Documentation and examples can be found [on this page](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)